# Vertical scroll snap doesn't work with Next.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scroll, next.js

I'm trying to get working this scroll snap css feature in my Next.js project. Haven't done such a feature yet. The article of reference is [this one](https://alligator.io/css/scroll-snapping/).
After applying `scroll-snap-type` to the parent and `scroll-snap-align` to children (start/center... all of them) my scroll behave the ordinary way. Can't get my head around what I'm missing.

Here's **index.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import '../index.css'

import Carusel from '../components/carusel'

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <Carusel />
  </div>
)

export default Home
```

Here's **carusel.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Carusel extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <section className='container'>
        <h1 className='child' >Slide 1</h1>
        <h1 className='child' >Slide 2</h1>
        <h1 className='child' >Slide 3</h1>
        <h1 className='child' >Slide 4</h1>
        <h1 className='child' >Slide 5</h1>
        <style jsx>{`
          .container {
            width: calc(100vw-(100vw-100%));
            height: 100vh;
            text-align: center;
            scroll-snap-type: y proximity;
            scroll-padding: 10px;
          }
          .child {
            height: 100%;
            scroll-snap-align: center;
          }
          .child :nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: red;
          }
          .child :nth-child(even) {
            background-color: green;
          }
      `}</style>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

export default Carusel
```

Here's **index.css**

```
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Scroll snap does work with next.js - just make sure you define the `scroll-snap-type` and `overflow: scroll` on the container that has the scroll-bar (for me it was body). The scrolling will also snap to nested children, not just direct child elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely because you are scrolling the body and not the `'container'`

```css
.container {
  width: calc(100vw - (100vw - 100%));
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  scroll-padding: 10px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.child {
  height: 100%;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.child :nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}

.child :nth-child(even) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<section class='container'>
  <h1 class='child'>Slide 1</h1>
  <h1 class='child'>Slide 2</h1>
  <h1 class='child'>Slide 3</h1>
  <h1 class='child'>Slide 4</h1>
  <h1 class='child'>Slide 5</h1>
</section>
```

PS: `scroll snap` isn't supported in Firefox

Comment: @moshyfawn if this answer is right mark it as the answer if not tell me what you don't understand or what doesn't work

Comment: It must be smth to do with compatibility issue, because your snippet doesn't work for me either. I currently use Linux with Firefox. For my project I ended up using [this react lib](https://github.com/lucafalasco/scroll-snap). Here's my [implementation](https://github.com/Moshyfawn/snap)

Comment: @moshyfawn wait a second I will make a PR

Comment: @moshyfawn check your github also I update my answer snapping should be apparent now

Answer (score 0):

In case if adding `scrollSnapType: "y proximity"` to the container doesn't work, try adding it to html tag. It works for me.